# html generated from a web service adding backslashes into the code

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio, web-services

I am generating html code from a web service. The html contains a table and table rows and columns. The output is not as expected. It is putting a backslash with every slash. Like the following.

```
<table class='table-fill'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th class='text-left' colspan=4>Patient name:A<\/th>
<\/tr>
<\/thead>
<tbody class='table'>
<tr>
<td class='text-left'>Age:<\/td>
<td class='text-left'>65<\/td>
<td class='text-left'>Blood Pressure:<\/td>
<td class='text-left'>142\/90 mmHg<\/td>
<\/tr>
<\/tbody>
<\/table>
```

I tried htmlencode but in that too the backslashes are still coming. Please help

code I am using is

```
string htmlstring = "<br><br><br><br>";
                        htmlstring = htmlstring + "<table class='table-fill'>";
                        htmlstring = htmlstring + "<thead>";
                        htmlstring = htmlstring + "<tr>";
                        htmlstring = htmlstring + "<th class='text-left' colspan=4>Patient name:" + c.Patname +"</th>";
                        htmlstring = htmlstring + "</tr>";
                        htmlstring = htmlstring + "</thead>";
                        htmlstring = htmlstring + "<tbody class='table'>";
                        htmlstring = htmlstring + "<tr>";
                        htmlstring = htmlstring + "<td class='text-left'>Age:</td>";
                        htmlstring = htmlstring + "<td class='text-left'>" + c.Age + "</td>";
                        htmlstring = htmlstring + "<td class='text-left'>Blood Pressure:</td>";
                      htmlstring = htmlstring + "<td class='text-left'>" + c.Bpr + "</td>";
```

Comment: The problem you are having its because to c# to generate the literal "/" needs to use an escape keychar which is "\". can you show how you are implementing your method?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer

The answer is simple: there is no backslash in the string!

What you're seeing is the Visual Studio debugger's representation of the string. Since you're using C#, it displays the string with the escape characters you would need to include to type that value as a string literal in your C# code. But those escape characters are not actually part of the string.